# Horizontal Scaling of CometD java clients

Tags: java, cometd

Can we scale a cometd java client horizontally?
I.e if I have a container subscribed to cometd, can I have one more clients running as docker containers for load balancing? If yes, how to make sure that each client receives unique data and doesn't duplicate.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "container" as it is not clear. A "container" is not subscribed to CometD channels, a CometD client is.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you can have as much clients as you want. Its all bout if the load balancer and server can keep up with the load.

In my company we do load test through CometD WebSocket. Sometimes we have up to 2000 parallel clients.

Comment: Yeah, that is indeed possible, but my question is, how to load balance among clients without data duplication.

Comment: Why do you need data that is not duplicated? And why do you need to load balance the clients? You should be more specific. Do you want to load balance the broadcasting from the server to the clients or the other way around?

Comment: Suppose the client is part of some application, may be say that its part of some email sending application. I would like to scale my email sending application for performance. So, each instance should be listening and responding to only one message, as the mails shouldnt be triggered multiple times.

Comment: So basically your client application is a consumer. You need to implement some kind of global queue, that each client with pull data from, or some global orchestrator, I would personally go with global queue. You need something like https://hazelcast.org/ implemented globally, on a separate JVM that has a queue, and you can set up your clients to read from that queue.

Comment: The actual purpose is for load balancing and resiliency. If I go for hazelcast, then again i come to the same scenario, where only one client is receiving data from the server.